# Doctrine static constructor in php

Tags: php, doctrine

Currently i am using Doctrine, starting up a connection via:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $config = new Configuration();
        $connectionParams = array(
            "url" => "mysql://root:@localhost/test",
            "charset" => "utf8",
        );
        $this->connection = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config);
    }
```

When using this, it will give me a connection object, that i have to pass into every class / place, where i want to use it.

Therefore i want to make it static, so that i can always access it everywhere with DB::$connection or a static getter for that.

So i copied the exact same function into a static constructor and just changed this:

```
self::$connection = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config);
```

After that for testing purpose i access it via this:

```
DB::construct();
$connection = DB::getConnection();
```

and pass the `$connection` variable on like i did before with the normal object instance. Should work right? Doesn't.

Error i am getting is:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in PATH/PDOConnection.php on line 104

and:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was
>   empty'

In the first query i am automatically trying to run. Anybody has a solution here? There isn't much content, when googling "doctrine static constructor" or anything like that. And i absolutely changed nothing except the `$connection` object i am giving into my main controllers on which they run queries.

Comment: `and pass the $connection variable on like i did before with the normal object instance` - but why is that, if you can just call `DB::getConnection()`?

Comment: Because i actually have to confirm if that will work, before i change about 200 lines of code wherever this $connection is passed on. This is the exact reason why i am doing it. It hurts to pass it on and on and on. I just want to be able to call DB::getConnection() and each place and its fine. So to make sure it actually works i accessed it via DB::getConnection() and then passed it on like the connection instance i had before. Doesn't work

Comment: Can you show the client code then?

Comment: What do you mean by client code? I simply instantiated the connection object before and now i just use DB::construct() and pass the $connection object on like before by naming it like $connection = DB::getConnection(). What client code?

Comment: You _do_ use `$connection`, right? That's the client code. Before that, you had to use $someObj->connection, or something similar.

Comment: Oh boy. That's the mistake. Thanks! I completely forgot that before it was like $obj->connection and now i pass the connection object itself. I guess the day was to long ;)